Freeze and CPU softlock
I keep having issue with crash and softlock of my CPU. I had that with older version and still with the last update. Does someone have an idea where this can come from with this journalctl ? I use hyprland on endeavouros
jjun 25 19:59:55 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: dell_smm_hwmon: SMM call took 369280 usecs!
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd-coredump[18465]: [] Process 1696 (Hyprland) of user 1000 dumped core.
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1696:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d90e44 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x94e44)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d38a30 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3ca30)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc213d204c3 abort (libc.so.6 + 0x244c3)
                                                                 #3  0x000062c913cf1827 _Z25handleUnrecoverableSignali (Hyprland + 0x13a827)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc213d38ae0 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x3cae0)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d90e44 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x94e44)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213d38a30 raise (libc.so.6 + 0x3ca30)
                                                                 #7  0x000062c913f5530e _ZN15CHyprOpenGLImpl5beginEP8CMonitorRK7CRegionP12CFramebufferSt8optionalIS2_E (Hyprland + 0x39e>
                                                                 #8  0x000062c913f700c3 _ZN13CHyprRenderer11beginRenderEP8CMonitorR7CRegion11eRenderModeN9Hyprutils6Memory14CSharedPoint>
                                                                 #9  0x000062c913f70812 _ZN13CHyprRenderer13renderMonitorEP8CMonitor (Hyprland + 0x3b9812)
                                                                 #10 0x000062c913de0807 _Z13handleWrappedP11wl_listenerPv (Hyprland + 0x229807)
                                                                 #11 0x00007bc21472e42e wl_signal_emit_mutable (libwayland-server.so.0 + 0x842e)
                                                                 #12 0x000062c913fd57f1 n/a (Hyprland + 0x41e7f1)
                                                                 #13 0x00007bc214457d90 drmHandleEvent (libdrm.so.2 + 0xed90)
                                                                 #14 0x000062c913fd589c handle_drm_event (Hyprland + 0x41e89c)
                                                                 #15 0x00007bc2147300a2 wl_event_loop_dispatch (libwayland-server.so.0 + 0xa0a2)
                                                                 #16 0x00007bc21473210f wl_display_run (libwayland-server.so.0 + 0xc10f)
                                                                 #17 0x000062c913e3fd89 _ZN17CEventLoopManager9enterLoopEP10wl_displayP13wl_event_loop (Hyprland + 0x288d89)
                                                                 #18 0x000062c913cb5a4b main (Hyprland + 0xfea4b)
                                                                 #19 0x00007bc213d21c88 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x25c88)
                                                                 #20 0x00007bc213d21d4c __libc_start_main (libc.so.6 + 0x25d4c)
                                                                 #21 0x000062c913cee4d5 _start (Hyprland + 0x1374d5)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1794:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8e552 pthread_cond_clockwait (libc.so.6 + 0x92552)
                                                                 #2  0x000062c913de09a1 n/a (Hyprland + 0x2299a1)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc2140e0c84 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6 + 0xe0c84)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1825:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1812:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1826:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1813:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1823:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1824:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1805:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1806:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1808:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 
                                                                 Stack trace of thread 1809:
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
                                                                 #1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
                                                                 #2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
                                                                 #3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@0-18402-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@0-18402-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
                                                                 #4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
                                                                 #5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
                                                                 #6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
                                                                 ELF object binary architecture: AMD x86-64
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@0-18402-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 polkitd[1519]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.34, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgen>6:51 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware d
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000019
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CPU: 18 PID: 3188 Comm: ThreadPoolForeg Tainted: P           OE      6.9.6-arch1-1 #1 8d3e363979c9a1730a7b5efa0421fcd4efd8406b
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 16 Plus 7630/0P6HCW, BIOS 1.15.0 04/29/2024
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RIP: 0010:zswap_entry_free+0xa7/0x170
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Code: 64 55 01 48 01 d0 48 c1 e8 0c 48 c1 e0 06 48 03 05 8e 64 55 01 48 8b 28 e8 36 2a dc ff 48 8b 4b 38 48 c1 ed 3b 48 85 c9 74 04 <48>>6:51 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: Started Power Profiles daemon.
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffb64c8a71f8b0 EFLAGS: 00010206
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000002 RBX: ffff9170b3d337d0 RCX: 0000000000000009
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RDX: ffff91714684a380 RSI: ffff9170b3d332d0 RDI: ffff9170b3d337d0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: ffff9170b0484640 R09: 000000000033000e
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R10: 000000000033000e R11: ffff91740f7fb000 R12: ffff9170b0484640
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R13: 03ffffffffffffff R14: ffff9170b0484648 R15: ffff917120bfdae0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9173ff700000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
                                                                 #0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1813:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1823:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1824:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1805:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1806:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
Stack trace of thread 1808:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)

Stack trace of thread 1809:
#0  0x00007bc213d8b4e9 n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x8f4e9)
#1  0x00007bc213d8ded9 pthread_cond_wait (libc.so.6 + 0x91ed9)
#2  0x00007bc20309d47e n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d47e)
#3  0x00007bc20307b22c n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x7b22c)
#4  0x00007bc20309d3ad n/a (iris_dri.so + 0x9d3ad)
#5  0x00007bc213d8eded n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x92ded)
#6  0x00007bc213e120dc n/a (libc.so.6 + 0x1160dc)
ELF object binary 
architecture: AMD x86-64
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: systemd-coredump@0-18402-0.service: Deactivated successfully.
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 polkitd[1519]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.34, object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgen>8:09 noah-inspiron16plus7630 bluetoothd[1401]: Endpoint registered: sender=:
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000019
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CPU: 18 PID: 3188 Comm: ThreadPoolForeg Tainted: P           OE      6.9.6-arch1-1 #1 8d3e363979c9a1730a7b5efa0421fcd4efd8406b
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 16 Plus 7630/0P6HCW, BIOS 1.15.0 04/29/2024
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RIP: 0010:zswap_entry_free+0xa7/0x170
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Code: 64 55 01 48 01 d0 48 c1 e8 0c 48 c1 e0 06 48 03 05 8e 64 55 01 48 8b 28 e8 36 2a dc ff 48 8b 4b 38 48 c1 ed 3b 48 85 c9 74 04 <48>>8:16 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1568]: Activating special unit Exit the
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffb64c8a71f8b0 EFLAGS: 00010206
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000002 RBX: ffff9170b3d337d0 RCX: 0000000000000009
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RDX: ffff91714684a380 RSI: ffff9170b3d332d0 RDI: ffff9170b3d337d0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: ffff9170b0484640 R09: 000000000033000e
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R10: 000000000033000e R11: ffff91740f7fb000 R12: ffff9170b0484640
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R13: 03ffffffffffffff R14: ffff9170b0484648 R15: ffff917120bfdae0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9173ff700000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000019 CR3: 00000001608b8000 CR4: 0000000000f50ef0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: PKRU: 55555558
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Call Trace:
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  <TASK>
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? __die_body.cold+0x19/0x27
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? page_fault_oops+0x15a/0x2b0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? exc_page_fault+0x81/0x190
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x26/0x30
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? zswap_entry_free+0xa7/0x170
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  zswap_invalidate+0x9b/0xb0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  free_swap_slot+0x18/0xd0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  __swap_entry_free+0x72/0x90
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  free_swap_and_cache+0x57/0x100
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  unmap_page_range+0x837/0x17a0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? mas_next_slot+0x153/0x6c0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  unmap_vmas+0xbd/0x1a0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  exit_mmap+0xff/0x3a0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  __mmput+0x3e/0x140
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  do_exit+0x2e0/0xaf0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? __pfx_futex_wake_mark+0x10/0x10
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  do_group_exit+0x30/0x80
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  get_signal+0x7e4/0x880
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  arch_do_signal_or_restart+0x3f/0x260
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x1b1/0x210
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x8f/0x190
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? futex_wake+0x8f/0x190
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? do_futex+0x125/0x190
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x127/0x1e0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x75/0x210
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? do_syscall_64+0x8f/0x190
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  ? __irq_exit_rcu+0x4a/0xb0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x76/0x7e
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RIP: 0033:0x74bd661744e9
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at 0x74bd661744bf.
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RSP: 002b:000074bc815ff150 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 000074bd661744e9
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000189 RDI: 000074bc815ff3d0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RBP: 000074bc815ff180 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000ffffffff
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 000074bc815ff3d0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  </TASK>
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Modules linked in: hid_logitech_hidpp uhid rfcomm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_seq snd_seq_device xt_conntrack xt_MASQUERADE nf_conntra>ited, status=1/FAILURE
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_soc_acpi_intel_match soundwire_generic_allocation snd_soc_acp>7:36 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: Starting Create System Users...
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  processor_thermal_wt_req mei_me snd_timer drm_display_helper spi_intel_pci i2c_i801 snd processor_thermal_power_floor i2c_smbus spi_int>
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel:  typec intel_ishtp xhci_pci_renesas idma64 vmd i8042 i2c_hid pinctrl_tigerlake serio wmi btrfs blake2b_generic libcrc32c crc32c_generic >7:36 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd[1]: Starting dracut cmdline hook...
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000019
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RIP: 0010:zswap_entry_free+0xa7/0x170
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Code: 64 55 01 48 01 d0 48 c1 e8 0c 48 c1 e0 06 48 03 05 8e 64 55 01 48 8b 28 e8 36 2a dc ff 48 8b 4b 38 48 c1 ed 3b 48 85 c9 74 04 <48>>7:36 noah-inspiron16plus7630 systemd-sysusers[262]: Creating group 'nobody' 
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RSP: 0000:ffffb64c8a71f8b0 EFLAGS: 00010206
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000002 RBX: ffff9170b3d337d0 RCX: 0000000000000009
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RDX: ffff91714684a380 RSI: ffff9170b3d332d0 RDI: ffff9170b3d337d0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: ffff9170b0484640 R09: 000000000033000e
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R10: 000000000033000e R11: ffff91740f7fb000 R12: ffff9170b0484640
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: R13: 03ffffffffffffff R14: ffff9170b0484648 R15: ffff917120bfdae0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9173ff700000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000019 CR3: 00000001608b8000 CR4: 0000000000f50ef0
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: PKRU: 55555558
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: note: ThreadPoolForeg[3188] exited with irqs disabled
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: note: ThreadPoolForeg[3188] exited with preempt_count 2
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
jun 25 20:00:41 noah-inspiron16plus7630 kernel: BUG: scheduling while atomic: ThreadPoolForeg/3188/0x00000000

And then I have big message saying that the CPU is soft-lock and I have this message for every CPU. It mostly happen with memory consumption and I think it my happen when the OS try to take some swap memory but I already had this issue in my previous installation and I had no problem with the swap. I don't have the journalctl from this period though
